# Click an element on one page and change an element on another page JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to click a button on a page (index1.html) and I want it to modify the color of some text that is actually on another html page (index2.html). Is this possible to do with jquery?

Everything I've tried doesn't work and I understand why: since to view the second page (index2.html), I need to refresh that page, the action is lost during that refresh. I know this can be done with angular or react but i really want to stick with jquery or javascript only.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: theres no code. its just a question

Comment: You can use [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) as an event-driven way of notifying the 2nd page. You'd `localStorage.setItem` on the first page, and listen for a [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) on the 2nd page.

Comment: gor for web scoket.

Comment: By the way, this is a legitimately focused conceptual question that should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

One option I can see is when navigating to `index2.html`, is to pass some query params. For example: `./index2?something=true&otherthing=false`. Then use js to get the query params on page load.

```js
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
searchParams.get("something"); // true
```

[For reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 1):

It can't be achieved directly neither with jQuery nor with React/Angular/vanilla JS.

You have 2 options both related with storing data.

1. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (or well cookie if you prefer and it makes sense).

Just store the information you want to pass in `index1.html` then check if it exists on `index2.html`, if so, use it.

2. Use backend

It's actually quite similar to the firs option but slightly more reliable (even though much more complex).

In this case, once the button on `index1.html` gets clicked, set a cookie with needed data/send data directly to the server with HTTP request.

This way you will have to play with data mostly on the server side.